# TypeScript - Error: <Property> does exist on type '{property: Type; }' | Error', Property <property> does not exist on type 'Errror'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have the following type. Which when I use in the following context is giving me this error:

```js
//Type
export interface MessageType<D> {
  type: Type;
  data: D | Error;
}

// Usage
export function functionName(): MessageType<{ prop: EntityType }[]> {
  return service().then(responseBody => {
    const firstMessage = responseBody[0];
    // The Error comes from here. In the "data.prop.map"
    firstMessage.data.prop.map(({ name }: EntityType) => anotherFunction(name));
  });
}
```

The error itself is the following. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this? Partial Types do not work either, and the `MessageType` is the correct one.

```
TS2339: Property 'prop' does not exist on type '{ prop: Type; } | Error'.   Property 'prop' does not exist on type 'Error'
```

Comment: I guess you're confusing the compiler, you mentioned that MessageType<D>, now while using it you're telling him that D==> EntityType and []?? How does it makes sense? Also what is EntityType can you mention that also?

Comment: In your code `MessageType` - return type function `functionName`, but not type `firstMessage`. Pay attention to type `responseBody` from `service()`

Comment: Well, the service is defined correctly. Also, this is a peculiar type, referring to WebSocket. Meaning I have an Array of messages coming in. Containing either EntityType, or Errors

Comment: EnittyType is an Objects with a key of `prop`. Example: `EntityType: {prop: {...}`

Comment: My response looks like this.. {type: 'DATA', data: {props: [{..}, {..}]}`..